# .htaccess allow extra characters at the end of URLS

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

If i have 100s of pages:

```
 http://www.example.com/category/product1/
 http://www.example.com/category/product2/
 http://www.example.com/category/product3/
 http://www.example.com/category/product4/
```

etc

I would like the pages to be also accessable via

```
 http://www.example.com/category/product1-1/
 &
 http://www.example.com/category/product1-2/

 http://www.example.com/category/product2-1/
 &
 http://www.example.com/category/product2-2/
```

Using ReWrite in .htaccess

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by `100s of pages like: http://www.example.com/category/product/` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps, this is what you're looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d # not a dir
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f # not a file
RewriteRule ^([^/]+/.+?)-\d+(/.*)?$ /$1$2 [L]
```

This would resolve `/any_category/any_product-[any_number]/` internally as `/any_category/any_product/`. If you want the browser URL to change as well use `[R=301,L]` instead.

Comment: Using Magento this seems to break some css

Comment: @AlexMcDaid Could you share what those `css` paths are like?

Comment: @AlexMcDaid Please try using `^([^/]+/.+?)-\d+(/.*)?$ /$1$2 [L]` which resolves relative path requests for any static resource (like css, jpg) with their ids removed as well.

Comment: You shouldn't be having any problems if you're using an absolute path to refer to your css (or one that starts with a `/`). Are you sure this is how you're including css in your html? Are there any other rules in your htaccess? Please, update the question if you do.